# Amcharts graph - Hyperlink for chart columns to custom URLs to open in a new tab/window

Tags: javascript, url, amcharts

I am trying to make a amcharts graph with columns linked to custom urls and want the urls to open in a new tab/window. I tried adding this code to the graph object but it does not work, it is opening link in same tab/window -

```
"listeners": [{
      "event": "clickItem",
      "method": function(event) {
window.open(event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url, '_blank');
      }
    }],
```

Please tell what I am doing wrong. I do not want to use Jquery and I am new to javascript.

This is my snippet -

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 2025,
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States"
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China"
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809,
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan"
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322,
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germany"
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114,
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France"
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984,
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India"
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711,
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spain"
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  }],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits",
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "clickItem",
      "method": function(event) {
window.open(event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url, '_blank');
      }
    }],
    "urlField": "url"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 20
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: If you assign `window.open()` to a `var` then *(as long as you have CORS access)* you can do like `newWindowVar.document.getElementById()` and the like. Or you could make a link to the specific page and use `target='_blank'`. Remember to remain compliant with XHTML you would want to assign the target attribute with JavaScript.

Comment: @PHPglue What is CORS access ? Can you try on this snippet or on this jsfiddle -  https://jsfiddle.net/1ayr47bx/1/

Comment: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. If you are creating both pages on the same domain, you shouldn't have to worry about it. If not in you would need permission from the other site to use JavaScript from your site on theirs.

Comment: @PHPglue I am very new to Javascript. That is why I have put the full snippet / jsfiddle. Can you please edit and show the working method in an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [urlTarget](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#urlTarget) such as:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits",
    "urlField": "url",
    "urlTarget": "_blank"
  }],
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"listeners": [{
      "event": "clickItem",
      "method": function(event) {
window.open(event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url, '_blank');
      }
    }],
```

to

```
listeners:[{
  event:'clickItem',
  method:function(event){
    open(event.item.url, '_blank');
  }
}]
```

Comment: I changed this in the Amcharts API code (Please see snippet in my question). But it still opens custom url in same tab/window on clicking on the column