# AmCharts 4 Donut Graph - HyperLink for Custom URL

Tags: javascript, charts, hyperlink, amcharts, donut-chart

I'm unable to get a hyperlink to [this](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/variable-height-3d-pie-chart/) donut chart in amcharts4. I made it successfully using [amcharts 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898995/amcharts-graph-hyperlink-for-chart-columns-to-custom-urls-to-open-in-a-new-tab) but am not getting it in amcharts4.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

I also referred to another [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898995/amcharts-graph-hyperlink-for-chart-columns-to-custom-urls-to-open-in-a-new-tab) but was unable to get help from it.

Here is my script:

```
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart3D);
chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this creates initial fade-in

chart.data = [
  {
    country: "India",
    litres: 501.9,
    url:"amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/clickable-links-in-tooltips/"
  },
  {
    country: "Czech Republic",
    litres: 301.9,
    url:"amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/clickable-links-in-tooltips/"
  },
  {
    country: "China",
    litres: 201.1,
    url:"amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/clickable-links-in-tooltips/"
  },
  {
    country: "Germany",
    litres: 165.8,
    url:"amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/clickable-links-in-tooltips/"
  },
  {
    country: "Australia",
    litres: 139.9,
    url:"amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/clickable-links-in-tooltips/"
  },
  {
    country: "Japan",
    litres: 128.3,
    url:"amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/clickable-links-in-tooltips/"
  }
];


chart.innerRadius = am4core.percent(40);
chart.depth = 120;

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries3D());
series.dataFields.value = "litres";
series.dataFields.depthValue = "litres";
series.dataFields.category = "country";
series.slices.template.cornerRadius = 5;
series.colors.step = 3;
series.urlField= "url";
series.urlTarge= "_blank"

}); // end am4core.ready()
```

Here is the HTML Part:

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

And The Css

```
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [property binding](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Property_fields) and bind the `Slice`'s [`url` property](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/slice/#url_property) to the `"url"` key in your data, e.g.

```js
series.slices.template.propertyFields.url = "url";
series.slices.template.urlTarget = "_blank";
```

Demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/6709f9e96d952ee15adfce67dde2ae8f

If `"url"` is present in the data, the slice will have their mouse cursor change to a pointer on hover and clicking it will take you to a link in a new window.

Answer (score 4):

```
series.slices.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {


   var url=ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.url
  console.log('currentTargt',url)

  window.location=url

});
series.targetUrl="_blank";
```

The above thing also worked for me.